# Doctrine 2 select empty field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a Symfony 2/Doctrine project that has to use a legacy database. I've created a Doctrine 2 entity form the existing database which generally works just fine. But I can't seem to get one case working: There are some database entries that have empty field (not NULL, just empty) which I want to select via a Doctrine query.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p FROM dtrcmsBundle:Page p WHERE p.articleName = :pageName'
)->setParameter('pageName', '');
```

Dose not seem to work. Any ideas how to select the empty fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As empty string is less than any character(I may be wrong) so we can compare with the lowest character in the character-encoding scheme, '0'. Following example shows what I mean.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p FROM dtrcmsBundle:Page p WHERE p.articleName < :pageName'
)->setParameter('pageName', '0');
```

Comment: Done some more test. Unfortunately, dose not seem to work in all cases. Will do some more testing.

Comment: Just a small change needed to make it work: Instead of using `a` you should use `0`. When using `a` you also get entries that are not empty but the field starts with a number.

Comment: **There are some database entries that have empty field (not NULL, just empty) which I want to select via a Doctrine query**. You wanted to get only empty fields not fields that start with a number!

Comment: And as a tried to say in the comment, `a` **also** selects fields that that start with a number and not the empty ones.